# Grafana table drill down dynamic link

Tags: grafana

I have 2 dashboards. In the first one there is a table such as

| pod | metric1 | metric2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa-1 | Two | Three |
| aaa-2 | Two | Three |
| bbb-1 | Two | Three |

If I drill down clicking on any value of the pod column then the dashboard 2 is opened passing the pod name. This works great so far.

What I need to do is to have a dynamic link. e.g.

- if pod == aaa* then open dashboard 2
- if pod == bbb* then open dashboard 3

Is it possible? if yes how can I do it?

any solution is appreciated (even if I have to add a hidden column with the dashboard link calculated at runtime and use the value of that column to drilldown)

Answer (score 0):

You already proposed the solution: Create a query, that generates the link*. dependent on the pod prefix (that is dependent on your data sources query language, so I cannot present a general solution) and then render the link in your list.

Comment: Thank you, even If I suggested the solution I am struggling implementing it. The datasource is prometheus if this helps.